# running grunt task twice results in error Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Use

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, purifycss

New to grunt I have successfully used it to run `purifycss`. Now I want to run `purifycss` twice with different arguments, and ideally concat the two resulting files afterwards. 
What I have so far is this `Gruntfile`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    purifycss: {
      bootstrap: {
        options: {},
        target: {
              src: [ 'live/*.twig' ],
              css: ['live/css/bootstrap*.css'],
              dest: 'purified_bootstrap.css'
                }
            },
      mycss: {
        options: {},
        target: {
              src: [ 'live/*.twig' ],
              css: ['live/css/mycss.css'],
              dest: 'purified_mycss.css'
                }
            }
      }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-purifycss');
  grunt.registerTask('purify', ['purifycss:bootstrap', 'purifycss:mycss']);
};
```

The output I get when running grunt purify from terminal:

```
> grunt purify
Running "purifycss:bootstrap" (purifycss) task
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any help on what's going wrong here appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the `src` and `css` options are actually files that exist? It's hard to say why this fails without seeing the directory structure

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, running both tasks seperately works just fine.

Comment: @jakerella directory structure is folder where grunt lives, /live where a set of twig templates sit and finally live/css where the css files are. So **folder/live/css**

Comment: Maybe the purifycss plugin is having an issue running both because the first one alters the array for files in `live/css/` and then the second task can't read it? Not sure...

Comment: You might want to run: `grunt purify --verbose`

Comment: @jakerella runing verbose gives `Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose
Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK
Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-purifycss" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/uk/dev/sites/shg/node_modules/grunt-purifycss/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/uk/dev/sites/shg/node_modules/grunt-purifycss/package.json...OK
Loading "purifycss.js" tasks...OK
+ purifycss
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ purify
`

Comment: and then `Running tasks: purify

Running "purify" task

Running "purifycss:bootstrap" (purifycss) task
Verifying property purifycss.bootstrap exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: write=false, info
Warning: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
`

Comment: Hmm... Looks like it couldn't find any files the second time through... not sure why though

Comment: I think you should post this as an issue on the GitHub repo for that plugin: https://github.com/purifycss/grunt-purifycss

Comment: Thanks @jakerella